Questions about pgfplot (ticks position, position of axis label, aspect ratio, etc)
I used the following code to plot a sequence:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 title={Graphique de la suite \(u_n = 3n^2 - 5\)},
    %samples=60,
    domain=0:5, xmax=5.5, xmin = -0.25,
    restrict y to domain=-20:80, ymax=80, ymin=-20,
    axis lines=left,
%    y=0.5cm/15,
%    x=0.5cm,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle, % Pour avoir des axes au milieu
    xtick={0,...,5},
    compat=newest,
    ytick={-15,0,15,...,75},
                x tick label style={below right},
 y tick label style={above left},
    compat=newest,
    xlabel=$n$, xlabel style={at={(1,0.15)}, anchor=north, above right},
    ylabel=$u_n$, ylabel style={rotate=-90,at={(0.05,1)}, anchor=south}
]
% Courbe de la suite
    \addplot[color=blue, thick] coordinates {
        (0,-5)(1,-2)(2,7)(3,22)(4,43)(5,70)
    };
    % Points marqués en rouge
    \addplot[only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.75, color=red}] coordinates {
        (0,-5)(1,-2)(2,7)(3,22)(4,43)(5,70)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

I get the following plot.

I have a few questions regarding the customization of axis labels and ticks in a TikZ/pgfplots environment:
Centering Axis Labels: I want the axis labels to be exactly centered on their respective axes. Currently, I'm doing this manually through trial and error, but I assume there’s a more straightforward setting to achieve this automatically. Is there a simple way to center them properly?
Tick Placement: How can I adjust the ticks so that they appear closer to their respective axes? I’d like the ticks to be positioned along the axis lines.
Displaying Zero Ticks: I’m trying to make sure the tick at zero is visible, but currently, it doesn’t show up. How can I ensure that the ticks at zero are displayed on both axes?
Square Axes: How can I force both axes to have the same scale, so that the units on the
-axis and
-axis are equal, resulting in a square plot?
Thanks a lot for your help!

axis equal will give you the same scale, but also the same domain.  There is also scale only axis combined with width,height, xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax.

I made a couple of minor simplifications.  I set the scale so that the grid formed 1cm by 1cm squares.  It turns out that middle lines have centered ticks by default.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 title={Graphique de la suite \(u_n = 3n^2 - 5\)},
    %samples=60,
    scale only axis, width=5.75cm, height=6cm,
    domain=0:5, xmax=5.5, xmin = -0.25,
    restrict y to domain=-20:80, ymax=80, ymin=-20,
    axis lines=middle,
%    y=0.5cm/15,
%    x=0.5cm,
    grid=both,
    xtick={0,...,5},
    compat=newest,
    ytick={-15,0,15,...,75},
                x tick label style={below right},
    y tick label style={above left},
    hide obscured y ticks=false,
    compat=newest,
    xlabel=$n$, xlabel style={at={(axis cs: 5.5,0)}, anchor=west},
    ylabel=$u_n$, ylabel style={rotate=-90,at={(axis cs: 0,80)}, anchor=south}
]
% Courbe de la suite
    \addplot[color=blue, thick] coordinates {
        (0,-5)(1,-2)(2,7)(3,22)(4,43)(5,70)
    };
    % Points marqués en rouge
    \addplot[only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.75, color=red}] coordinates {
        (0,-5)(1,-2)(2,7)(3,22)(4,43)(5,70)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

